# What does "premium" mean in "ten reasons to go premium"?

Tags: meaning

I have a requirement to translate a sentence to Farsi. It's a game that says:

> Go premium to receive some more options...

I don't know what is the exact meaning of *premium*. Any details about the grammar and meaning would be appreciated.

Comment: I should think that *premium* would be in the dictionary, and would tell you all you need to know.  You should specify what it was with the dictionary definition that you didn’t understand, or sought clarification on.

Comment: @tchrist I did try that. But I can't figure out how it means here in this situation. "Premium" has lots of meanings as you already know. I hoped maybe you could help me about it. :)

Comment: "... reasons to spend more money on the expensive version."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To augment Barrie's answer about the game, I'd say that a *premium* version of the game has, to use a  cliché, all the bells and whistles than the stripped-down basic version. I don't play games, but my son does. Premium versions seem to come with more weapons, more options for each character and for each player, and other benefits that cost money. Premium (or *paid*) versions of antivirus and antimalware software provide realtime protection and automatic updates, but the basic free versions don't always provide that. A first-class airplane seat is a *premium* seat because it has more space, better food, better drinks, and better service than an economy class airplane seat. A premium version of an automobile has a bigger and better air-conditioner, leather upholstery instead of plastic or cloth or naugahyde (artificial leather), electric controls for the side-view mirrors, an electric radio antenna, maybe, a USB connector in the glove compartment for your MP3 player, a roof rack for your luggage and dog, a fancier radio & CD player, a built-in GPS, a camera for taking videos of your trip (maybe in front of the rear-view mirror), a little radar device in the front as well as the back of the car to let you know when you're too close to objects, maybe a couple of cameras to show you whats behind your rear wheels and your front wheels, etc.

Comment: It was the best. Thank you dear Mr Franke. You made my day. :)

Comment: @Mohammad Goudarzi: You're welcome. Happy to be helpful. :-)

Answer (score 4):

As an adjective, *premium* describes something of superior quality, so *Go premium* is probably an invitation to buy a better version of the game.

Comment: Thank you Barrie. You are great as always. Could you just give me more details about it? I mean the word "Premium".

Comment: The original meaning IIUC relates to an "extra" payment or additional cost. Via the implication that something costs more because it is better, it has also come to be used as a description for the best model/version/whatever of something that comes in multiple versions (for comparison, the cheapest might be described as "basic" or "economy"). This use seems to be more prevalent in US English.

Comment: It depends on what you want to know, Mohamed. The Oxford English Dictionary's entry runs to more than 4000 words. Bill gives quite a lot of information in his answer.

Comment: Thank you @BarrieEngland. I'm sorry but it's 'Mohammad' not 'Mohamed'. I'm not the messenger by the way,, ;D

Comment: I'm sorry, محمد